# Using TCP + AsyncTask To Keep Connection Open and Listening for Data Being Sent From Server

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask, inputstreamreader

Hi Stackoverflow members! Heres my issue...
1) Connect To a TCP Server *CHECK
2) Send the Initial Packet & Receive from Server (VB.NET)  *CHECK

**NOW MY ISSUE**

I'm trying to keep my connection alive, and continue to listen for incoming data. I tried using a timer but I had no luck. any help would be highly highly appreciated

```
  package com.WheresmySon;


  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.BufferedWriter;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
  import java.net.Socket;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import java.util.Timer;
  import java.util.TimerTask;


  public class TcpClient extends Activity {
private static BufferedReader in;
private static BufferedWriter out;
private static Socket s;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new TcpClientTask().execute();

}


class TcpClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 1234;
    private boolean error = false;
    Boolean SocketStarted = false;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", TCP_SERVER_PORT);


                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

            //send output msg
            String outMsg = "VER:Android,LAT:28.111921,LNG:-81.950433,ID:1038263,SND:0,VDO:0,TXT:Testing";
            out.write(outMsg);
            out.flush();

            Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);

            //accept server response

            String inMsg = in.readLine();

            Log.i("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);



            //close connection
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        if(error) {
            // Something bad happened

        }
        else {
            // Success

    }
}

}

//replace runTcpClient() at onCreate with this method if you want to run tcp client as a service
private void runTcpClientAsService() {
    Intent lIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), TcpClientService.class);
    this.startService(lIntent);
}

  }
```

TcpClientService.java

```
 package com.WheresmySon;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
      import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.IBinder;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class TcpClientService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    runTcpClient();
    this.stopSelf();
}
private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 1234;
private void runTcpClient() {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", TCP_SERVER_PORT);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        //send output msg
        String outMsg = "TCP connecting to " + TCP_SERVER_PORT + System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
        out.write(outMsg);
        out.flush();
        Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);
        //accept server response
        String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Log.i("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);
        //close connection
        s.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` is not the best place for any network stuff, especially for non-statless connections like `Sockets`. Best approach is to use `Service`. You could try to search for any code example about how to use Services to handle socket connection in Android. This code will never works fine.

Comment: Hi Evos. If you look at the bottom of the code there is a runTCPClientAsService() Should I use that instead?

Comment: If this is an example project, and it already has correct implementation of `TcpClientService`, yes it better to use it instead of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Evo. Here is the TcpClientServer() lets say I use this how would I go about "Listening" for data coming in and keep this connection open as a Service?

Comment: @Ruben this is very big question and  it includes a lot of information about programming and using Android framework. First of all check documentation about Services (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)   and if you are not proficient in Android you could try to use it in a simple way like int this tutorial (http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)